# How to set the text alignment of edit text to bottom programatically?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have checked following properties(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)  but none is working. How to set the text alignment of edit text to bottom programatically?

Comment: Try to use : editText.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

Comment: this does not work and it sets alignment of editText

Comment: can you provide the xml

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is because you have set the `EditText` height as wrap_content, try giving it a hardcoded value:

Example : `android:layout_height="50dp"`

Answer (score 1):

yes that can be done with the help of `android:gravity="bottom"`

eg below

```
  <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:text="abc india"
            android:gravity="bottom" />
```

programatically

```
editText.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```